# How can I limit the volume of audio on Windows by decibel level?

Tags: windows-7, audio, software-rec, sound-card, hardware-rec

I enjoy listening to music at high volumes, but I'm concerned about possible long-term hearing loss. [Articles covering this question](http://www.sciencedaily.com/videos/2007/0610-mp3_players_how_loud_is_too_loud.htm) suggest limiting audio volume to under 85 decibels.

Is there:

- A setting built in to Windows or a third-party software that can control the system volume slider in units of decibels?
- Or, a standalone third-party software that can limit audio playback by decibel level?
- Or, a hardware device that I can use reasonably easily to cap audio decibel levels?

[A more reliable source about noise-induced hearing loss.](http://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/hearing/pages/noise.aspx)

Comment: Without a calibrated system output, this is only possible with a feedback loop of somethine that measures the loudnes then adjusts/cuts volume based on the measured output.  1 watt could be 80dbor less or 100db+; so active control based on feedback would be the only way.

Comment: To add to Damon's comment, decibels is determined by the device that actually delivers the sound (headphones, speakers), your distance from it, and other factors. Computer speakers are typically self-powered, so the computer has little control over the sound pressure delivered to your ears. Decibels don't mean anything to the computer unless you introduce something to measure the sound at your ears and use that to adjust the computer's volume level. There is no OS setting or software that can do that, at least not without additional hardware, other than crudely, arbitrarily limiting levels.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can solve this is by using dynamic range compression (DRC).

The DRC algorithm basically works as follows: for low decibel (dB) sounds, the output signal matches the input signal, but after some dB threshold, the sound is artificially limited. Loud sounds still sound "louder" than other sounds, but their maximum dB is greatly decreased.

Here's a simple figure illustrating the concept:
[Dynamic range compression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpnkh.png) ([credits](https://auphonic.com/blog/2011/07/25/loudness-normalization-and-compression-podcasts-and-speech-audio/))

You can learn one way to do this with Windows via the following forum post: https://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/15386-how-to-guide-for-windowsgame-audio-compression/

The main idea is to use a "virtual" cable to route your output audio signal to a program, have the program apply DRC to the signal, and then route that altered signal to your speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a volume limit cable. For example: [Hamilton Audio Safe(TM) Control Cable for Headphones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H9U7KFC)

Comment: Although this is an old question, you've offered a good answer. It could use some improvement though. Links can become broken over time, so it is important to add details to the answer rather than just link. Please take a minute to [edit] your answer with some detail of how the cable works and why it would be the proper answer for this question.

Answer (score -2):

i don't know how to change volume depend on decibel. but if you concerned about your ears, i think it's good to active Loudness Equalization system. it's help you to decrease volume for your healthy (or something like that...). for that, write this on Start menu:
-> type speaker (but don't press enter)
-> select Manage audio devices (for me it was the 5th result which appeared after typing "speaker")
-> select the Playback tab (should be the default one already open)
-> click to select the specific speaker hardware you want -> then click Properties.

At the new popup select the Enhancements tab, then in the middle section below you should see the Loudness Equalization option among the others.

P.S: if you want to read more about this, look at [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/127496-how-can-i-control-volume-decibels-bandwidth.html). in fact i write the answer of this topic for you. and it's my resource.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. It seems like they suggest using a hardware device. Loudness equalization isn't what I want; it makes the music sound bad.